# ADD for more than two numbers in spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

Normally when I use functions in Google Sheets I can do something like this `=K:K/J:J` and get that column to update for its specific row for example.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BJ6p.jpg

However with the SUM function this adds all of them. With a function like:

```
=SUM(D:D,C:C,E:E,G:G,F:F,H:H,I:I,J:J,K:K,L:L
```

and copy pasting it in a bunch of rows leads to every row having the same number instead of them depending on the numbers in their specific row. I tried changing to the ADD function however this only can add two at a time. As a temporary fix I have been using this function:

```
=SUM(O3,Q3,S3,U3,W3,Y3,AA3,AC3,AG3,)
```

and changing the number value for each row.

Is there a way to make a single formula that I can copy paste instead, something similar to the ADD function but with more than two values?

Answer (score 1):

You might use [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) in a formula constructed like so:

```
=sum(indirect("O"&row()),indirect("Q"&Row()), ...  )
```

but a better solution might be a data layout revision.